# How do I get a value randomly from a list in Jython script?

Tags: java, python, jython, grinder

```
lists = portTest.lists(arg1, arg2) 

// this returns the lists from webservice in java  
//  public String[] list1; 
//  public String[] list2;public String[] list3;

// i want to get the random element in the list,
// not the first, second or any selected item. 
elementinthelist = lists.list1[0]
```

How do i generate the random element from the list

I am writing a testscript in Jython. I am calling the service using Grinder tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, use [random.choice](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
import random
elementinthelist = random.choice(lists.list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Choose a random integer between 0 (inclusive) and the length of the list (exclusive).

In regular Java this would look like

```
Random rand = new Random();
int randIx = rand.nextInt(lists.size());
Object element = lists.get(randIx);
```

Comment: thank you, but i need it in jython, and i need to select the first list with random element.